# Wordpress: What could be done if I can see the /wp-includes

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress. What damage could be done if a user on the open internet can see my wp-includes and content file. Would their be a way for the user to download/ view any php file that do not 500 error? Im check someone web page but never real worked with Wordpress.

Comment: _"Would their be a way for the user to download/ view any php file that do not 500 error?"_ - not if the server isn't misconfigured and does not _parse_ those files.

Comment: Well. I open a run some of them. Only the automatic youtube video thing. I guessing I could change the channel It shows.